# Google Play doesn't show my app?

Tags: android, google-play

Last night I loaded a new application in Play Store, but I don't show it in the store.
When I look applications loaded by the developer (me), there is not.
I can only see if in the console I click on View in Google Play Store.
this is my developer url :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Amarildo+Aliaj

Can center the fact that twice they have suspended my applications?
So is it just a matter of time, or I'm missing something?

Comment: DId you publish the app?

Comment: This is off-topic because it's about Google's acceptance process, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Google suggests to wait for a maximum of 24h after you click the publish button for your app to be published. So, wait for 24h and if your app is not displayed then contact them. Maybe the fact that you have apps rejected before slows down the process.

Before that make sure that you have published your app for **Production** and not as Alpha or Beta.